# ANTLR4 : Does it write anything to local file system while lexing and parsing?

Tags: security, encryption, antlr4

I am currently developing a grammar like SQL which takes highly critical data (Ex: Customer's Name or Customer's Phone Number) as input. For the sake of simplicity assume that input string which needs to parsed will not be more than 4 lines (will be lite, can be handled as in-memory without much issue).

From information security perspective, I want to ensure that this critical data does not gets written to file system in raw form during lexing and parsing. (Basically want to adhere to [Encryption at Rest Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_at_rest#Encryption) or simply avoid that local file system hit).

I haven't read through the auto-generated lexer & parser code, reason being the implementation is governed by ANTLR4 and it can change in future.

Q1. Does ANTLR4 writes to local file system at all ? or in other words is it secure enough to handle critical data ?

Comment: Please ignore my second question.

Q2. Hence wanted to know if anybody has faced similar kind of situation. If yes then how did they dealt with it ?

Comment: If swapping is enabled or the device running your code supports suspend-to-disk, everything can end up on disk (albeit not in any filesystem, usually).

Comment: That's a really good insight, I will definitely check app-host configuration and JVM configuration to avoid potential data leaks.  Thanks Peter.

Answer (score 0):

> Q1. Does ANTLR4 writes to local file system at all ?

No, it does not write the input source you're passing into the lexer/parser to disk. And although not explicitly mentioned in the API that it doesn't store input source to disk, it would be extremely odd to change this behaviour in future version of ANTLR.

> or in other words is it secure enough to handle critical data ?

That is for you and/or your company to decide.

Your 2nd question is not a good fit for stackoverflow (subjective/open-ended questions) as per https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: thanks for answering, followed your suggestion to remove second question.

Q2. Hence wanted to know if anybody has faced similar kind of situation. If yes then how did they dealt with it ?